# Употребление изобилующих глаголов

Tags: наклонение-глагола

Что является современной литературной нормой: “он достиг цели” или “он достигнул цели”? “Мы прибегли к хитрости” или “мы прибегнули к хитрости”?

Comment: https://kartaslov.ru/проспрягать-глагол/достигнуть - достиг, прибегли